# How to get all the webpage elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am entirely new to webpage scraping and have been looking at a few YouTube videos and online to get me started.

So far, I have been trying to get all the webpage elements from the following website: https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating

Here is what I have so far:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating'


def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


# for i in range(1, 103):


def getnextpage(soup):
    page = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'pagination'})
    return page


soup = getdata(url)
print(getnextpage(soup))
```

This prints:

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
<li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=5">5</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=6">6</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=7">7</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=8">8</a></li>
<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=101">101</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=102">102</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which is not exactly what I am looking for, I wanted to return only the html elements from the first page to the last page for example:

```
https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=1
https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=2
...
..
.
https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating&amp;page=102
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium with python to simulate a browser and get the site then click on the button as many times as you want or until the button is no longer there. I chose to do it only 10 times because the list seems to be almost infinite.

Then I printed out all the URLs on the site, but you can just as easily store them in a list instead.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

options = Options()
options.headless = False

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.letsride.co.uk/routes/search?sort_by=rating")
load_more = True
#while load_more:
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    try:
        load_more_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/section/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/a')
        load_more_btn.click()
    except:
        load_more = False
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a cleaning function to get rid of non-url elements - basically you need to check each element against a variable that has the canonical url form (https:// ....)

i haven't exactly tested the proof on your code, sorry, hope you'll be able to add it accordingly.

```
tester = "https://www.letsride.co.uk" #modify this var accordingly to your needs

def cleaner(data):
    clean_data = []
    for items in data:
        if items[0:len(tester)] == tester:
            clean_data.append(items)
    return clean_data
```